# ¿Cómo evitar "Out of memory" excepcion con Bitmap?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando con imágenes (escaneos de documentos) y quiero mostrar el encabezado y el pie de esas imágenes. Estoy usando este fragmento de código:

```
Bitmap imagen=new Bitmap(files[0]); //files es string[] files[0]="C:\\escaneo.jpeg"
Bitmap encabezado=imagen.Clone(rEncabezado, imagen.PixelFormat);
Bitmap pie=imagen.Clone(rPie, imagen.PixelFormat);
pictureBoxEncabezado.Image=Encabezado;
pictureBoxPie.Image=Pie;
```

Los dos rectángulos usados en la función `Clone()` ya están definidos y la excepción ocurre en en

```
Bitmap pie=imagen.Clone(rPie, imagen.PixelFormat);
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Si la idea es cargar la imagen porque no usas

```
string filePath = files[0];

pictureBoxEncabezado.Image= Image.FromFile(filePath);
pictureBoxPie.Image= Image.FromFile(filePath);
```

usando el [Image.FromFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile(v=vs.110).aspx) asignas directo la imagen al control

Al clonar estas duplicando en memoria el contenido del archivo

Para cortar una imagen podrias evaluar

[Cropping Images](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30725/Cropping-Images)

como veras se realiza un `Dispose()` de la imagen una vez trabajada, podrias intentar

```
Bitmap imagen1 = Image.FromFile(files[0]) as Bitmap; 
Bitmap encabezado = imagen1.Clone(rEncabezado, imagen1.PixelFormat);
pictureBoxEncabezado.Image = encabezado;
imagen1.Dispose();


Bitmap imagen2 = Image.FromFile(files[0]) as Bitmap; 
Bitmap pie = imagen2.Clone(rPie, imagen2.PixelFormat);
pictureBoxPie.Image = pie;
imagen2.Dispose();
```

Comment: Lo que necesito es recortar la imagen para mostrar el encabezado y el pie (Por eso uso el metodo Clone()). file tiene la ruta de la imagen que se va a recortar. Como puedo hacer esto sin generar la excepcion?

Comment: edite la respuesta, quizas plicando el dispose resulte

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ve esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166690/memoria-insuficiente-no-se-control%C3%B3-outofmemoryexception saludos!