# Memoria insuficiente (No se controló OutOfMemoryException)

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, timer

estoy haciendo un tipo slider/carrusel de imágenes en Windows Form [VB.NET], estoy usando un **Timer** para que cada cierto tiempo se vayan presentando las imágenes en un **PictureBox.** Hasta ahora el programa me hace lo que pretendo, solo que me causa un gran problema, cada que se va cargando una imagen en el **PictureBox** me va aumentando el consumo de memoria del sistema hasta llegar al punto de tronar el programa.

El código que uso para hacer esta tarea:

```
Dim lista As New List(Of String)
Dim i As Integer = 0
```

> Obtener el nombre de los archivos (jpg) de un directorio y almacenarlos en una lista.

```
Sub llenardatos()
    Dim carpeta As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Promo\")
    For Each File As FileInfo In carpeta.GetFiles("*.jpg")
        lista.Add(File.Name.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

> Al ejecutar el programa, cargar el primer elemento de la lista.

```
Private Sub frmP_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    llenardatos()
    Timer1.Start()
    Timer1.Interval = 3000
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Promo\" + lista(0))
End Sub
```

> Uso de Timer, mostrar en PictureBox los elementos de la lista, si llegan al final, reiniciar el contador.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    i = i + 1
    Label1.Text = i
    If i = lista.Count Then
        i = 0
    End If
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Promo\" + lista(i))
End Sub
```

Espero me puedan orientar, que es lo que me causa el problema, cabe destacar que las imágenes son ligeras ya que la img más pesada es de 468KB

Comment: consulta... al rededor de cuanto tiempo pasa antes de todo se caiga?,
trata de poner un try catch dentro de tus funciones para saber exactamente en que linea de código genera el error, eso ayudaría bastante para saber por donde va el tema.

Comment: Alrededor de 3 min, todo depende del **Timer1.SetInterval**, mientras más rápido se pasan las imágenes,  mas rápido se cae el sistema. He estado observando el comportamiento del programa y me he percatado de que cuando cambio la propiedad **SizeMode** de mi PictureBox a Zoom mas rápido se cae el programa, cuando lo cambio al valor "StretchImage" es más lento el consumo de recursos, pero si va en aumento.

Comment: mismo escenario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107837/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-out-of-memory-excepcion-con-bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu problema podría deberse a que no haces `Dispose` de las imágenes que no vuelves a usar.

Bajo esta premisa, y basandome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808753/right-way-to-dispose-image-bitmap-and-picturebox), deberias de hacer Dispose de las imagenes cada vez que actualizas el `PictureBox`:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(
    ...
    var imagenNueva = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Promo\" + lista(i))

    var imagenVieja = PictureBox1.Image;
    PictureBox1.Image = imagenNueva; 

    if(imagenVieja != null)
        ((IDisposable)imagenVieja).Dispose();
```

VB.net no es mi fuerte, por lo que ruego que me perdones si mi sintaxis es incorrecto.

Comment: no es la primera pregunta que hacen sobre esto en el sitio hispano, por algún lado he visto. Inclusive la misma respuesta. Saludos :D

Comment: la encontré: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107837/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-out-of-memory-excepcion-con-bitmap

Comment: Si he implementado el algoritmo pero sigue el aumento el consumo de los recursos. Más lento pero hasta ahora después de 9 min sigue en aumento..

Comment: Es posible que haya otro Memory Leak en alguna parte, pero sin tener mas ejemplos de tu codigo sera dificil resolverlo =\

Comment: No estas usando algun otro lugar objetos como Bitmaps, fonts, meshes, textures, etc?